# specifying multiple files in appender

Tags: java, logback

Is it possible to append multiple files to an appender, at the moment my appender is as following, it only outputs to 1 file. I want to append to another file in addition.

```
<appender name="LATENCY_LOGGER"     class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <File>${log.dir}/${LOGNAME}.metrics.csv</File>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${log.dir}/${LOGNAME}.metrics.%d{yyyyMMdd}.csv.gz</FileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.fed.service.util.logging.TradeMetricsFilePatternLayout">
              <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>   
           </encoder>
</appender>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No.
A logback `RollingFileAppender` is an instance of [`FileAppender`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) which works with a [single file](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/0dd3c19e1fe3f50cf7a13c08024cdbe9cc8b62b1/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.java#L195).

Define another appender for your second file. There you can also specify other useful things for the second file, like the rolling policy, archival, etc.